# EmguCV Pre-filter before Canny edge in OpenCV Demostrator

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I've been working with OpenCV and EmguCV for the first time.
I needed to process some images and implemented EmguCV but since I'm very newbie on this I don't even know the commands/filters so I looked up for an application to demonstrate OpenCV filters and found one, named "OpenCV Demonstrator" available [here](https://opencv.org/opencv-demonstrator-gui.html)

So far so good, I've found exactly what I need (Canny edge detection) in the application but the problem is I cannot figure out what filter/command it applies before applying the Canny filter named "Pre-filter"

Here is the screnshot of app:

[image: OpenCV Pre-filter on Canny edge detector]

The application has source files available but it has been written in a different language so I don't know where to look.

What does that "Pre-filter" refers to ? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: A simple [`blur`](https://github.com/tsdconseil/opencv-demonstrator/blob/6000979da8f6f61649a3323d19f5bfd5ce0a1703/ocvdemo/src/demo-items/gradient-demo.cc#L51)

Comment: thanks for the help! Is it a direct openCV command or an app function?

Comment: OpenCV -- Here are links to relevant [original docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#blur) and [EmguCV docs](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/2a1f73c2-77fb-3835-e3f3-496f243d3cac.htm)

Comment: ohh, ok. I was temporary using and old OpenCV version that cvinvoke.blur was missing, my bad. it's ok now, thanks a lot!